# How to parallelize the sparse matrix-matrix (SpMM) product with OpenMP for the COO format?

Tags: c, openmp, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I recently coded a multithreaded version of the sparse matrix-vector (SpMV) product using a COO storage format:

```c
void dcoomv(SparseMatrixCOO *A, double *x, double *y) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) y[i] = 0.;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:y[:A->m])
  for (int i=0; i<A->nnz; i++) {
    y[A->row_idx[i]] += A->val[i] * x[A->col_idx[i]];
  }
}
```

Considering the potential for race conditions of the COO SpMV, this is about as good as it gets and it does not so bad. Actually, it does better than MKL's `mkl_sparse_d_mv` with COO, which I think is not parallelized at all.

Now, I would like to parallelize the sparse matrix-matrix (SpMM) product. I did two attempts. First, I wrote

```c
void dcoomm_pll1(SparseMatrixCOO *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  for (int i=0; i<(A->m * nvec); i++) Y[i] = 0.;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:Y[:A->m*nvec])
  for (int i=0; i<A->nnz; i++) {
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
      Y[A->row_idx[i] + vec * A->m] += A->val[i] * X[A->col_idx[i] + vec * A->n];
    }
  }
}
```

This, however, does not speedup but rather slows down the code in parallel.

Second, I did

```c
void dcoomm_pll2(SparseMatrixCOO *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  for (int i=0; i<(A->m * nvec); i++) Y[i] = 0.;
  for (int i=0; i<A->nnz; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
      Y[A->row_idx[i] + vec * A->m] += A->val[i] * X[A->col_idx[i] + vec * A->n];
    }
  }
}
```

which, again, leads to some slowdown.

For reminder, the sequential implementation of `dcoomm` is given by

```c
void dcoomm(SparseMatrixCOO *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  for (int i=0; i<(A->m * nvec); i++) Y[i] = 0.;
  for (int i=0; i<A->nnz; i++) {
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
      Y[A->row_idx[i] + vec * A->m] += A->val[i] * X[A->col_idx[i] + vec * A->n];
    }
  }
}
```

My sequential version is about 30% faster than MKL's `mkl_sparse_d_mm` with COO. However, both my multithreaded versions are much slower than `mkl_sparse_d_mm`.

As I tried parallelizing the COO SpMM function with both `dcoomm_pll1` and `dcoomm_pll2`, none of which offers satisfactory performance, I wonder how to parallelize the COO SpMM so as to improve parallel perfomance.

Comment: A lot depends all sorts of factors. For instance, however many threads you tried, did you try half that? What matrix sizes did you try? Array reduction carries more overhead for large arrays, so try matrices that are much smaller and much larger. Next: are you wedded to COO? If you do more than a single product, first convert to CRS and then use that repeatedly. Random idea: if you absolutely need COO and your matrix is very sparse, do not store the output vector as as vector but a `std::map` and then merge those into a vector in the end.

Comment: I am using matrices from the SuiteSparse Matrix Collection ranging from 178k large with 1M non-zero values, to 5M large with 59M non-zero values. Indeed, I didn't expect the reduction to work well. No, I'm not set on COO, but I'm trying to do an overview of all MKL's supported formats, i.e., COO, CSR, CSC and BSR, and some more. I managed to write sequential and parallel SpMV functions which do as well and even sometimes better than `mkl_sparse_d_mv`. However, I struggle a lot more to match the performance of `mkl_sparse_d_mm` with my own SpMM routines, both in parallel and in sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory access pattern is not contiguous in your matrix-matrix multiplication code, therefore leading to more cache misses. Cache misses are already bad for sequential code, and even worse for multithreaded codes. Why not calling nvec times a sequential version of dcoomv, and parallelize this loop? You don't even need a reduction.

```c
void dcoomm_pll3(SparseMatrixCOO *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
     dcoomv_seq(A, X + vec * A->n, Y + vec * A->m);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. It is much better like this. I now get some speedup. However, it is still 2X slower than `mkl_sparse_d_mm` when using 8 threads. And when using 1 thread, my code was initially 30% faster than `mkl_sparse_d_mm`, but now it's about 40% slower.

Comment: Is `mkl_sparse_d_mm` multithreaded or not? The MKL routines are usually quite hard to beat in terms of speed, they are highly optimized with blocking, explicit SIMD intructions, and even sometimes assembly pieces. So I'm a bit surprised if your initial version was faster (all the more given the bad memory access pattern).

Comment: Yes, `mkl_sparse_d_mm` is multithreaded, and quite efficiently so. My own made routines for SpMV and SpMV_T are a bit faster than `mkl_sparse_d_mv` for COO, CSR and CSC in series and in parallel; and near same speed for BSR. I hope to achieve similar speed and scaling for my SpMM routines with respect to `mkl_sparse_d_mm`.